# Calling twitter bootstrap tab function from within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

With bootstrap-tab.js I want to activate a tab, calling it from within another function. 
Html:

```
<a onClick='activate_tab()'>Activate Tab</a>
<ul class='nav nav-tabs hydro' id='nav_tabs'>
  <li class='active'><a href='#1' data-toggle='tab'>First</a></li>
  <li class=''><a href='#2' data-toggle='tab'>Second</a></li>
  <li class=''><a href='#3' data-toggle='tab'>Third</a></li>
</ul>
<div class='tabbable'>
  <div class='tab-content'>
    <div class='tab-pane active' id='1'>content first</div>
    <div class='tab-pane ' id='2'>content second</div>
    <div class='tab-pane ' id='3'>content third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am able to activate the tab on page load with the following:

```
<script>jQuery(function($){$('#nav_tabs li:eq(2) a').tab('show');})</script>
```

And the tabs activate properly by clicking on the respective anchor elements. The following does not work:

```
function activate_tab(){
    //process other data...then goto tab
    alert(1);
    $('#nav_tabs li:eq(2) a').tab('show');
    alert(2);
}
```

I am new to javascript/jQuery.

[EDIT] I stripped the original page down to just what's shown above and it works. So, likely a conflict with other functions. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: When and how is `activate_tab()` being called?

Comment: @JustinY in test mode, by onClick of an anchor. Ultimately it will be an onChange of a text input.

Comment: When you say that `activate_Tab()` doesn't work, what do you mean? What happens when it's called? When you show tab 2, are you making sure that tab 1 and tab 3 are hidden?

Comment: do you place `active_tab()` within jquery wrap i.e `jQuery(function($) {});`

Comment: @JustinY (I edited the activate_tab() above) Alert '1' fires, Alert '2' does not. Do I need to call a function that hides the other tabs?

Comment: @thecodeparadox I have not placed it within a jquery wrap. Trying that now...

Comment: I stripped the original page down to just what's shown above and it works. So, likely a conflict with other functions. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

try this if you dont

```
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){

      function activate_tab(){
        //process other data...then goto tab
        alert(1);
        $('#nav_tabs li:eq(2) a').tab('show');
        alert(2);
      }

    });
   </script>
```

Comment: I've added this and I do not receive Alert '1' after clicking the respective anchor.